# Disable button in another view

Tags: ios, swift, button

is it possible to disable a button which is in another view?

If I try to do this:

```
refreshbutton.enabled = false
```

I have this in both .swift files:

```
@IBOutlet var refreshbutton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

the program stops and I get a fatal error.

EDIT:

I tried following:

```
 let otherviewcontroller: SerialViewController = SerialViewController (nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
 let button1 = otherviewcontroller.refreshbutton
 let loading1 = otherviewcontroller.loading
 loading1.showLoading2()
 button1.enabled = false
```

Why am I able to access the showLoading2() function in the other controller, but why can I not access the button ? It throws a fatal exception and say "button1" is nil, but why?

Comment: It might help to post the code to the program and the specific error you are receiving.

Comment: You should make the names unique.  While it's not necessarily required, it will help with making sure you're calling the correct property on the correct button.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the left navigation button from inside an `UIViewController` like this, without using any `IBOutlet`:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO
```

To disable the right navigation button:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it by sending the notification & observing it in the class you want to disable it

Notification can be sent using below code in your view from where you want to disable the button

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("kDiableRefreshButton", object: nil)
```

Receive notification in class where you want to disable the button

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "diableRefreshButtonNotification:", name:"kDiableRefreshButton", object: nil)
```

Implement method which will be called on behalf of notification

```
func diableRefreshButtonNotification(notification: NSNotification){
//Disable your button or Do whatever stuff you want
}
```

Don't forget to remove the notification while your view is getting dealloc

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "kDiableRefreshButton", object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously possible. You just meed to reference that viewController first and then access the "refreshbutton" of that SerialViewController

Example -

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
if let otherviewcontroller = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? SerialViewController {
    let button1 = otherviewcontroller.refreshbutton
    let loading1 = otherviewcontroller.loading
    loading1.showLoading2()
    button1.enabled = false
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is not executed, because viewController is nil !? Have you got any ideas?

Comment: can you share the code with me, i would be aable to help better.

Comment: I've edited my first post with the code I am using. thank you for your help

Comment: It seems that it returns nil, so nothing is executed inside the if, but I don't know why ?!